# Check for column in backupset table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Created a script to show last backup locations, sizes and dates

```
SELECT DatabaseName = x.database_name,
        LastBackupDate = x.backup_finish_date,
        BackupSizeKB = x.backup_size,
        LastBackupFileName = x.device_name,
        left(right(x.device_name, 21),17) as Backup_Device_Date,
        type = x.type
        FROM (  SELECT  bs.database_name, bs.type,
                case 
                    when exists(
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='backupset' and column_name = 'compressed_backup_size'
                    )
                    then cast(round(max(bs.compressed_backup_size/1024),0) as numeric)
                    else cast(round(max(bs.backup_size/1024),0) as numeric)
                end as backup_size,
                max(bs.backup_finish_date) as backup_finish_date,
                max(bmf.physical_device_name) as device_name
          FROM  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
                  JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset bms ON bmf.media_set_id = bms.media_set_id
                  JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bms.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
          WHERE   bs.is_copy_only = 0
          GROUP BY bs.type, bs.database_name) x
WHERE x.database_name not in ('master', 'model', 'msdb')
AND x.type IN ('D')
ORDER BY DatabaseName;
```

The only problem, is that I get the following error when its executed on a SQL Server 2005 Enterprise 9.00.3042 64bit

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid column name 'compressed_backup_size'.

If I change the **then/else to**

```
case 
when exists(
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='backupset' and column_name = 'compressed_backup_size'
)
then 1
else 0
end as backup_size
```

I get 1 or 0 for backup_size depending on whether *compressed_backup_size* exists in backupset.

```
database_name   type    backup_size backup_finish_date  device_name
model   I   0   2013-09-02 18:30:19.000 Data Protector_(DEFAULT)_model_163022971_0
msdb    I   0   2013-09-02 18:30:22.000 Data Protector_(DEFAULT)_msdb_163022971_0
```

So in spite of using **CASE WHEN THEN ELSE** to check for the existence of *compressed_backup_size*, I'm still getting an error. Any thoughts on why the **THEN** argument is being parsed when the column *compressed_backup_size* clearly doesn't exist ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @JonSeigel Thanks, that worked out great. Can you put that in an answer so I can check it off?

Comment: `left(right(x.device_name, 21),17) as Backup_Device_Date` does not look right to me as it is not a date .. should not it be something like Backup_Device_name + the precision is also wrong .. as it truncates the name as well ...

Comment: @Kin Hi, yes using the string functions was a best effort attempt. Then there is also the fact that some of the dates are in US Style MM/DD/YY and others are in European style DD/MM/YY. That's why I added the x.backup_finish_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic SQL to hide that column from the parser in 2005. All columns are checked to make sure they exist before the query runs.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SET @sql = N'
SELECT DatabaseName = x.database_name,
        LastBackupDate = x.backup_finish_date,
        BackupSizeKB = x.backup_size,
        LastBackupFileName = x.device_name,
        left(right(x.device_name, 21),17) as Backup_Device_Date,
        type = x.type
        FROM (  SELECT  bs.database_name, bs.type,' +
                case 
                    when exists(
                        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='backupset' and column_name = 'compressed_backup_size'
                    )
                    then N'cast(round(max(bs.compressed_backup_size/1024),0) as numeric)'
                    else N'cast(round(max(bs.backup_size/1024),0) as numeric)'
                end + N' as backup_size,
                max(bs.backup_finish_date) as backup_finish_date,
                max(bmf.physical_device_name) as device_name
          FROM  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
                  JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset bms ON bmf.media_set_id = bms.media_set_id
                  JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bs ON bms.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
          WHERE   bs.is_copy_only = 0
          GROUP BY bs.type, bs.database_name) x
WHERE x.database_name not in (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'')
AND x.type IN (''D'')
ORDER BY DatabaseName;';

EXEC(@sql);
```